# Service Stack - route attribute for complex request class

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I want to use class OfferFilter to handle request for offers:

```
public class OfferFilter
{
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
    public bool ShowAllLanguages { get; set; }
    public int? SearcherSectorId { get; set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public int? RegionId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int? AskingPriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int? AskingPriceTo { get; set; }
    public bool AskingPriceSelected { get; set; }
    public int? SalesRevenuesFrom { get; set; }
    public int? SalesRevenuesTo { get; set; }
    public bool SalesRevenuesSelected { get; set; }
    public int? IncomeFrom { get; set; }
    public int? IncomeTo { get; set; }
    public bool IncomeSelected { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make a route attribute for that? Using POST would be easier but it will be GET request. Normal route string will be enormous and very error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

See the wiki page on [Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing). You only need to register the path info for the Service, and you're still able to use any of the properties in the QueryString, e.g:

```
[Route("/offers/search")]
public class OfferFilter { ... }
```

Lets you call the above service with any combination, e.g:

```
/offers/search?city=XXX
/offers/search?city=XXX&Age=20
etc.
```